# ORA-01031 Error message "insufficient privileges” with Entity Framework - Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I am currently doing a project that uses ASP.NET WebForms and Entity Framework version 5 with Oracle, but it generates an error when I try to insert a new record to the database, this is my code:

```
MODELCLASS MON = new MODELCLASS();
MON.PROP = "CO";
MON.VALU = "COP";
MON.CREATED_DATE = System.DateTime.Now;

context.MODELCLASS.AddObject(MON);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The problem occurs when the line `context.SaveChanges()` is executed, it generates the following exception:

`OracleException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`

I was investigating about the generated error and I found that it could be lack of permissions to the user with whom I am currently doing the insertion, but when I try with that same user in the **Oracle SQL Developer** manager, it allows me to insert the record.

Can entity framework request different privileges for insert?

Comment: Can you query the `session_roles` and `session_privs` data dictionary views in the two connections?  Are there any differences?

Comment: Double-check the connection string in he .exe.config file in your /bin/debug if running a debug config build for instance. It may be using a different account than you expect.

Comment: Are you on same machine when you are using Oracle SQL Developer?  What credentials are you using with Oracle SQL Developer?  Either the connection string parameters are not same in c# as SQL Deveopler.  Or you are not running with same credentials in c#.  When you run c# from inside VS you are not running with Admin rights.  So one possible solution is to start VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @StevePy You were right, I was looking at a connection string from a different project that was referenced in the current project.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a dummy error, I was looking at the configuration file of a referenced project and there was a connection string that was not being used.